# Is authorize.net old test server still active?

Tags: authorize.net

The old authorize.net test server was https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll but at some point changed to apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api. The new one expects XML. Our cart is passing an encoded url string. The production server we are using is secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll and it still works but the test server does not. I just created a new account on the sandbox but the old test site doesn't seem to accept my new credentials. What am i missing? Am I going to have to convert my custom cart to pass XML to use the test server?

Ashley

Comment: This seems like a question that should be asked of Authorize.net directly.

Comment: Both of the ../transact.dll endpoints you mention are active but they can only be used for the older AIM payment transaction, but not for customer profiles. The other ../request.api endpoint is for  the full Authorize.Net API using XML which includes everything listed in the API Reference http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/

Comment: Thanks. I asked auth.net directly via chat and was told both still worked but it seems the old test server doesn't like my new test credentials created via the new developer site. I'll call them and open a ticket.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **customer support** question. [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) .

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to confirm that both old and new test servers still work. I found an issue with the config in our shopping cart that resolved this issue.